# Starting Read required files in advance fails

Tags: boot, mount

If I boot my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro Laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, I get these messages in my boot process:

```
$ cat $(locate boot.log)|grep required

 * Starting Read required files in advance                                  [fail]
 * Stopping Read required files in advance (for other mountpoints)          [ OK ]
```

My mounted partitions are:

```
$ dfc
FILESYSTEM  (=) USED      FREE (-) %USED AVAILABLE     TOTAL MOUNTED ON 
/dev/sda7   [================----]   80%     13.0G     63.9G /
none        [--------------------]    0%      4.0K      4.0K /sys/fs/cgroup
udev        [=-------------------]    0%      3.9G      3.9G /dev
tmpfs       [=-------------------]    0%    798.6M    800.1M /run
none        [--------------------]    0%      5.0M      5.0M /run/lock
none        [=-------------------]    0%      3.9G      3.9G /run/shm
none        [=-------------------]    0%    100.0M    100.0M /run/user
/dev/sda11  [=================---]   80%      6.4G     31.9G /home
/dev/sda6   [====================]   99%    576.0M     54.3G /media/Daten
/dev/sda5   [===================-]   92%      5.1G     67.5G /media/Win8
```

The boot continues and everything seems to work fine, but 
what does this mean and do I have to worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

This message is generated my Ureadahead and means that you had a mountpoint in your fstab that didn't have any files on it needed during boot.

You do not have to worry about this message.

#### Additional information: What is Ureadahead?

Ureadahead is described on its [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ureadahead):

> It is used during boot to read files in advance of when they are needed such that they are already in the page cache, improving boot performance. Its data files are regenerated on the first boot after install, and either monthly thereafter or when packages with init scripts or configs are installed or updated. ureadahead requires a kernel patch included in the Ubuntu kernel.